# How to derive this relation about this periodic function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, inequality, periodic-functions

Let the function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$ f(x) \colon= \begin{cases} \lvert x \rvert \ & \mbox{ if } \ -1 \leq x \leq 1, \\ f(x-2) \ & \mbox{ otherwies}. \end{cases} 
$$
Then of course 
$$ f(x+2) = f(x) $$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Am I right?

How to derive the following inequality about $f$? 
$$ \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \lvert x-y \rvert $$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

This inequality of course holds for all $x, y \in [-1, 1]$.

And, if $x=y$, then the inequality becomes an equality and holds trivially.

How to derive this inequality for *all* $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \neq y$?

PS:

Based on the comments below, I would like to revise my definition of the function $f$ as follows:

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined such that 
>   $$ f(x) = \lvert x \rvert \ \mbox{ if } \ -1 \leq x \leq 1, $$
>   and such that $f(x+2) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Hope this definition is now sound enough.

Comment: This function isn't well defined. How would you define $f(-2)$? Your definition says it would be $f(-2-2)=f(-4)$. But then $f(-4)=f(-4-2)=f(-6)$ and so on. I presume you meant "$-1\leq x \leq 1$" in the first part of the definition.

Comment: @MPW exactly. You're right. I've just edited my post to correct the error. I'm baffled at how I left that $1$ out!!

Comment: Yes, it seemed a reasonable conclusion since you mention it holds for $x,y\in[-1,1]$. But what about my other qualm? The function is not well defined.

Comment: @MPW how come it is not well-defined? You see, I've specified the function on a closed interval of length $2$ and extended the definition periodically, with a period of $2$. Can you please clearly show in a detailed answer as to why this function is not well-defined?

Comment: I did. Plug $x=-2$ into your definition. It does not satisfy the condition on the first line ($-1\leq -2\leq 1$ is false), so it falls into the "otherwise" condition on the second line. That means you are defining $f(-2)$ to be $f(-2-2)$, i.e., to be $f(-4)$. But what is $f(-4)$? You run into the same problem, and find that it is $f(-6)$. But what is $f(-6)$? etc. It never stops.

Comment: In other words, as written, you are not extending the "base part" periodically. You would need to handle $x>1$ and $x<-1$ differently. Perhaps $f(x-2)$ in one case and $f(x+2)$ in the other?

Comment: @MPW I think your observation about my definition as it appears is correct, but I guess you understand what I mean to write. So may I edit my post to make the correcttion explicit?

Comment: Perhaps $$f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|,&-1\leq x<1\\((x+1)\mod 2)-1,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @MPW you might wanna consider revising your last comment.

Comment: @MPW please have a look at my post again. I've just added a PS.

Comment: Your modification does the job. My comment is correct and does the same thing. (Also, comments cannot be edited after a couple of minutes.) Note that technically, you should *not* define the function at both ends of the base interval since the definition at one end determines the value at the other end by periodicity. As it happens, they coincide, so there is no conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66595/discussion-between-saaqib-mahmuud-and-mpw).

Comment: @MPW now that the issue of well-definedness is settled, I'm eagerly awaiting an answer to my primary question.